Fonts are filled squares...?
Im new to ubuntu, and using a virtual machine (UTM) to run ubuntu, and it seems like in files, and things possibly built into ubuntu are just like, filled squares or something? im very confused, so please help soon? ( i dont know how to do screenshots on linux, sorry but no images bc dumb.) i think im on version 20.04 or something? please help, im way too new to linux to work around on this

This question is similar to: All fonts on Xubuntu are now boxes. Everything is illegible. Help. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The other reason I've experienced this is because I've set a specific font as default for some app; then I subsequently delete that font, thus the system has nothing to display... switching the app to an installed app was the fix in my case (only some apps do this; other apps use a different installed font if you delete the chosen font)
